# Matrix Table with R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I am trying to get the structure where the Location is the unique row, Lab is the unique Row, and the account is inside the matrix.

I have tried tables and have not been to get it 100% correct.

**End Result:**

[image]

```
sample:
structure(list(Location = c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 
1003, 1003), Lab = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2), Account = c(53127, 
28724, 23646, 53128, 28725, 23647, 53130, 28727)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a `matrix`, then use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(Account ~ Location + Lab, df1)
```

---

Or consider `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`, and then convert to `matrix`

```
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Lab, values_from = Account) %>% 
   column_to_rownames('Location') %>% 
   as.matrix
```